# How to programmatically login to Facebook oauth2 api

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, oauth

### Background:

I have written a Node.JS script that successfully connects to the Facebook Graph API through my facebook app. I can read data when I give it an oauth `access_token`, I want this script to run on my server every night to store some data. I have done a lot of research of both the facebook api, oauth and similar questions on stack overflow. I am searching the `/search/?type=event&q=query` endpoint

### Problem:

However, Facebook returns a 60 day `access_token` through the oauth2 login process that required me to create an `express` server that simply initiates the oauth2 process, allows the user to login, and receives the `access_token` code and I am storing it.

I want the script to save data so that my server can provide access to updated data every day. I don't want to have to remember to login to generate the key once every 60 days.

### Question:

Is there anyway to receive a oauth2 `access_token` without setting up an `http` or `express` server?
More importantly, how do I get the `access_token` without manually having to running that server every ~60 days.

### Code:

The Module I am using requires the `access_token` and `client_secret`

```
fs.readFile('./facebookAuthServer/oauth.txt', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    fbNode.setAuthorization({token: data, clientSecret: authSettings.clientSecret});
    // Use the auth for next call
    fbNode.fetchItems(displayItems);
});
```

Is there some way to spoof headers? or could I use a short lived access token and refresh it? Anyway to refresh a 60 day token? Has anyone created a server side implementation of Oauth2 that does not require visiting the FB login more than the first time?

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can refresh your own access token using [**Grant**](https://github.com/simov/grant) and [request](https://github.com/request/request).

First you need an OAuth client server up and running:

```
var express = require('express')
var session = require('express-session')
var Grant = require('grant-express')

var grant = new Grant({
    server:{host:'dummy.com:3000', protocol:'http'},
    facebook:{
      key:'[APP_ID]',
      secret:'[APP_SECRET]',
      scope:['user_about_me','user_birthday'],
      callback:'/callback'
    }
  })

var app = express()
app.use(session({secret:'very secret'}))
app.use(grant)

app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.query))
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Oh Hi', 3000)
})
```

Next you need an HTTP client that will simulate the browser request:

```
var request = require('request')

request.get({
  uri:'http://dummy.com:3000/connect/facebook',
  headers:{
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 ...',
    cookie:'datr=...; lu=...; p=-2; c_user=...; fr=...; xs=...; ...'
  },
  jar:request.jar(),
  json:true
}, function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  console.log(body)
})
```

### How you use it:

1. Register OAuth app on Facebook and set your *Site URL* (I'm assuming `http://dummy.com:3000`)
2. Add `127.0.0.1    dummy.com` to your hosts file
3. Configure and start the server from above
4. Navigate to `dummy.com:3000` in your browser
5. Open up the Developer Tools and navigate to the Network tab, make sure `Preserve log` is checked
6. Navigate to `http://dummy.com:3000/connect/facebook` and authenticate as usual
7. Take a look at the authorize request in the Network tab and copy the relevant headers to the HTTP client example (the `user-agent` and the `cookie`)
8. Run the HTTP client code (that's the code you are going to execute from time to time, the server should be running as well)

### Resources:

- [Introduction about how to use Grant](https://scotch.io/tutorials/implement-oauth-into-your-express-koa-or-hapi-applications-using-grant)
- [Grant documentation](https://github.com/simov/grant)
- [Request documentation](https://github.com/request/request) - see the options section

### Module:

I wrapped the above code into a module https://github.com/simov/facebook-refresh-token

Answer (score 0):

Start with reading the docs, it's all described there, instead of guessing:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#refreshtokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4#login

It's somehow a pity that you don't write **WHAT** you want to query via the Graph API, because depending on that you could either use a non-expiring page access token or an app access token, which also doesn't have to be renewed, instead of an user access token.

There's no way to automatically extend the long-lived access token. The user must visit your app again.

Comment: `I have done a lot of research of both the facebook api, oauth and similar questions on stack overflow.` I have read those pages, however I was hoping that someone had done something similar before, run a script daily that simulates the "user" visiting the app but the user is my server. I added to my post that I am trying to query the `search` type `events`

Comment: As the docs outline, the search for events require a user Access Token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4 There is no way to automatically renew such token on the server side. As stated in the docs I linked