# Post/share automatically to linkedin company page from server

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to post to my company page directly from my server, but I have a hard time understanding how the authentication works. All examples + the documentation seem to require you to have a callback where the "visitor" is promted with a form to confirm the access. But in my case, my app is supposed to only post to my company page and I didn't plan on building a gui at all.

I have setup the Client Id and Client Secret in the Linkedin developer section.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are the only one that's going to use the app, you still need to execute the OAuth flow and therefore authorize your own app to use your account. You can use [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant) for that.

Another thing to note is how LinkedIn handles scopes. They changed how the permissions work earlier this year, so for certain permission you'll have to submit your app for approval.

Lastly LinkedIn doesn't give you a `refresh_token` so in order to refresh your `access_token` once it expires you'll have to use a similar hack as the one I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444237/how-to-programmatically-login-to-facebook-oauth2-api/31502187#31502187) for Facebook.

Comment: Thanks, Grant seems to be a great middleware for my purpose.